# Opening modal from function in pure javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to open a modal with a function in pure javascript (not jquery).

Component from where i am calling function:

```
<div class="col-sm-5 offset-sm-5" 
    style={{ bottom: "60px", marginBottom: "20px", marginTop: "23px" }}>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onClick={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>Save</button>
</div>
```

Function code:

```
handleSubmit=()=>{
    document.getElementById('exchangehouse').style.display = "block"    
}
```

Modal code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exchangehouse" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
    aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: bootstrap uses jQuery, what is the purpose for opening it using pure javascript?

Comment: Same as @JulianPaoloDayag said, bootstrap uses `jquery`. And with `react`, why do you want to open like this, you can toggle a state variable and then switch the modal Show/Hide with the reference of that modal. Why you want to do it like this?

Comment: @JulianPaoloDayag It is possible . Me Also I want to use modal without javascript because I am doing a chalenge that restict the use of jquery

Answer (score 9):

Are you searching for this?

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Your Contents</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Don't copy from W3School

Comment: Can you explain  if (event.target == modal) {        modal.style.display = "none";} -> I check if the target event is modal and then hide it?

Comment: Copied from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp)

Comment: this maybe a little off-topic, but I never understand why people hate w3school so much.. I thought that website provides useful simple tutorials for basic stuffs like this?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a modern, pure ES6 implementation of a modal window.

I also included some simple open/close hooks.

```js
class ModalWindow {
  constructor(options) {
    this.opts = Object.assign({}, ModalWindow._defaultOptions, options)
    this.modal = document.querySelector(this.opts.selector)
    this.initialize()
    this.addEventHandlers()
    this.afterRender()
  }
  initialize() {
    if (this.opts.headerText) {
      this.query('.md-dialog-header-text').textContent = this.opts.headerText
    }
    if (this.opts.htmlContent) {
      this.query('.md-dialog-content').innerHTML = this.opts.htmlContent
    } else if (this.opts.textContent) {
      this.query('.md-dialog-content').textContent = this.opts.textContent
    }
    if (this.opts.theme) {
      this.modal.classList.add(`md-theme-${this.opts.theme}`)
    }
  }
  addEventHandlers() {
    this.query('.md-dialog-header-close-btn').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      this.setVisible(false)
    })
    if (this.opts.mode !== 'modal') {
      this.modal.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        if (e.target === this.modal) {
          this.setVisible(false)
        }
      })
    }
  }
  afterRender() {
    if (this.opts.show === true) {
      this.setVisible(true);
    }
  }
  setVisible(visible) {
    this.modal.classList.toggle('md-dialog-visible', visible)
    if (visible) {
       this.onOpen() // class method override or callback (below)
       if (typeof this.opts.onOpen === 'function') {
        this.opts.onOpen(this.modal)
       }
    } else {
      this.onClose() // class method override or callback (below)
      if (typeof this.opts.onClose === 'function') {
        this.opts.onClose(this.modal)
       }
    }
  }
  query(childSelector) {
    return this.modal.querySelector(childSelector)
  }
  // Example hooks
  onOpen() { }
  onClose() { } 
}
ModalWindow._defaultOptions = {
  selector: '.md-dialog',
  show: false,
  mode: 'modal'
}

class MyCustomModalWindow extends ModalWindow {
  constructor(options) {
    super(options)
  }
  onOpen() {
    console.log('Opened!') // or you can use options.onOpen
  }
  onClose() {
    console.log('Closed!') // or you can use options.onClose
  }
}

let modal = new MyCustomModalWindow({
  show: true, // Show the modal on creation
  mode: null, // Disable modal mode, allow click outside to close
  headerText: 'Hello World!',
  htmlContent: '<p>This is an example of the popup.</p>',
  theme : 'dark',
  onClose : (self) => {
    console.log('Another close hook...')
  }
})
document.querySelector('#show-modal-btn').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  modal.setVisible(true)
})
```

```css
.md-dialog {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.md-dialog.md-dialog-visible {
  display: block;
}
.md-dialog .md-dialog-window {
  border: 1px solid #888;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 10% auto;
}
.md-dialog .md-dialog-header {
  position: relative;
  width: calc(100% - 0.5em);
  height: 1.667em;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.33em;
  line-height: 1.667em;
  padding: 0.125em 0.25em;
  background-color: #DDD;
}
.md-dialog .md-dialog-header-close-btn {
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: bold;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 0.875em;
  height: 0.875em;
  line-height: 1em;
  padding: 0.1em;
  color: #7F7F7F;
}
.md-dialog .md-dialog-header-close-btn:before {
  content: '\2715';
}
.md-dialog .md-dialog-header-close-btn:hover,
.md-dialog .md-dialog-header-close-btn:focus {
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #F00;
}
.md-dialog .md-dialog-content {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.25em;
}


/** Example Dark Theme */
.md-theme-dark.md-dialog {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
.md-theme-dark.md-dialog .md-dialog-window {
  border: 1px solid #666;
  background-color: #111;
  color: #EEE;
}
.md-theme-dark.md-dialog .md-dialog-header {
  background-color: #000;
}
.md-theme-dark.md-dialog .md-dialog-header-close-btn {}
.md-theme-dark.md-dialog .md-dialog-header-close-btn:hover,
.md-theme-dark.md-dialog .md-dialog-header-close-btn:focus {}
.md-theme-dark.md-dialog .md-dialog-content {}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.1/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<button id="show-modal-btn">Open Modal</button>

<div id="myModal" class="md-dialog">
  <div class="md-dialog-window">
    <div class="md-dialog-header">
      <div class="md-dialog-header-close-btn"></div>
      <div class="md-dialog-header-text">$header</div>
    </div>
    <div class="md-dialog-content">$content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Two questions:  a)if (e.target === this.modal) {          this.setVisible(false)} : I do not understand, but I think that e.target checks for all clicks not related to modal. b) your code is newer compared to the [w3school one](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp) but so much longer and with another plugin normalize. So is it really more robust to use it instead of the simple one from the link? Maybe it is like driving an old car compared to a new one. If you know the how-to, take the old one..

Comment: @Timo normalize is not a plug-in. It’s a CSS normalized that makes the CSS you add appear very similar in any browser. It’s actually preferred for any website. Also, W3 Schools is not the best site for learning JS. Checkout http://w3fools.com

Comment: Well.. "Today, W3Schools has largely resolved these issues and addressed the majority of the undersigned developers' concerns. For many beginners, W3Schools has structured tutorials and playgrounds that offer a decent learning experience. Do keep in mind: a more complete education will certainly include MDN and other reputable resources" But for another day..

Answer (score 2):

In Bootstrap 5 (Beta 1) this gets as simple as this:

Your button (having onClick function call):

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick='openModal()'>
        Launch demo modal</button>
```

Your Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1"
        aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                        aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">...</div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"
                        data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And finally, the "pure" java script function:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function openModal() {
  var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('myModal'), {  keyboard: false });
  myModal.show();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Ingredients? Bootstrap js?

Comment: No. Pure (vanilla) javascript

Comment: Seriously, after searching for 3 hours. this "pure" javascript oneliner did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

well usually the option of modal for visibility is managed in state as boolean type.

you have to change the value of visibility as true(which is open) or false(and close), if there is no function that make visibility as false then you can't close the modal.

which mean is you need to use 'function' to change the 'value of visibility' that where in 'state' to control the modal view.

in react way.

```
view =( open modal )==> action === ( visibility) ==> state ===( change the value)===> view
```

and also your question is very abstractive.

anyway i hope that my answer can help you.